# How to configure a hotkey/shortcut to activate a macro in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2007, macros, hotkeys

Is there a way to configure Outlook 2007 so by pressing a **[CTRL]+[*letter*]** combination, a macro is activated?

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem and it is really a pity if that should be impossible.

Answer (score 3):

This MSDN [blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/richardb/binding-outlook-macros-to-a-keyboard-shortcut) shows how you can add macros to the toolbar then use an Alt keyboard shortcut to access them.