# Auto-Hide Ribbon with keyboard in Outlook and PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using this macro to Auto-hide ribbon in Word and Excel:

```
Sub HideTheRibbon()

    CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
    
End Sub
```

How can I assign this snippet to keys(keyboard shortcut) in Outlook and PowerPoint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure a hotkey/shortcut to activate a macro in Outlook 2007?](https://superuser.com/questions/171885/how-to-configure-a-hotkey-shortcut-to-activate-a-macro-in-outlook-2007)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it gives the same info as given on the link posted on the previous comment. The same should also apply to PowerPoint.

Comment: No. I'm using `ctrl+shift+a` in Excel and Word. I would like the same shortcut in those two apps.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio The "answer" to the question you linked isn't really an answer since it is just a link to another article. I think it's fair to answer the question here and then mark **that** question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Just checking the way Reddy mentioned below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the method described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/60c9f51f-0de8-4254-bfe0-75923ad8595a/how-to-assign-shortcut-key-to-vba-macro-added-to-outlook-2016-message-ribbon?forum=Office2016ITPro). It does not assign keyboard keys directly to the macro, but use an inserted button on the ribbon, and the keyboard keys that will be displayed when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to reach the button as  workaround.

> 1. Go to File > Options > Customize Ribbon.
> 2. Choose commands from Macro, add this custom button to a new tab. Save the settings.
> 3. In Outlook, press Alt to view keyboard shortcuts and follow it to your new Tab and new button.

The combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd> and other keys will be your keyboard shortcut. The same method could also apply to PowerPoint.

Comment: Add I would like to assign key directly to the macro.

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL-SHIFT-F1` is now a working keyboard shortcut for desktop outlook running on windows, to toggle autohide of menus & ribbon (i e "fullscreen" / "zen" mode).

( This is working on Win10
*[*Version 10.0.19042.1826*]* & *Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20394) 64-bit* )

I could not find any description of this in any help anywhere. The CTRL+F1 shortcut to toggle (show/hide) the ribbon is documented here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-the-ribbon-in-office-d946b26e-0c8c-402d-a0f7-c6efa296b527